# use express.js stating web server,and fontend use vue.js

Tags: express, url-rewriting, single-page-application, vue-router

Using vue.js(including vue-router) to make up the view and using express to make up the backend.

---

My question is that how to rewrite then URL with using **SPA**.
for example, start width then URL `http://localhost:8080` and link to `http://localhost:8080/foo` it works, but when I **refresh** the page in URL
`http://localhost:8080/foo` it shows me **404** error.

---

So how can I write the URL like the function of **.htacess** in **apache** to rewrite the URL?

Comment: where are you defining the address for your backend, can you show that?

Comment: app.use(express.static('public')); i just use static filed and the index.html in the  "public" fied and just visit the service ip xxxx width port 3000

Comment: how are you telling your frontend to talk with your respective backend?

Comment: just visit the url that backup has define like it app.get('/', function (req, res) {
 // res.send(req)
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

Comment: i meant to ask, if you are having different frontend and backend, there must be somewhere you are telling your frontend to talk to a particular backend address, what is that backend address